# Does magical ammunition stack with a magical weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

One of my players has a +1 shortbow, and recently found some +1 arrows. If he fires a +1 arrow from a +1 bow, will the bonus to attack and damage be +1, or +2?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to 5e designer Jeremy Crawford, "**Bonuses stack, unless a feature or item tells you otherwise.**" Therefore, firing a +1 arrow from a +1 shortbow results in a +2 to the attack ***and*** damage rolls. The [tweet exchange](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/12/05/arrow-1-bow-2-magic-bonus-stack/) occurred on November 28 - December 4, 2014 and is below.

@rwallace8665 asked:

> @JeremyECrawford already have a question. Ranger with Arrow +1 and bow +2. Do the bonuses stack, or take the higher?

Crawford answered:

> @rwallace8665 **Bonuses stack, unless a feature or item tells you otherwise.** And remember that magic ammunition loses its magic when it hits.

@rwallace8665 asked:

> @JeremyECrawford thought so, but thanks for verifying. I'm going to guess that rolling +1 ammo on the random [*DMG*] table means one, not a quiver?

@JeremyECrawford replied:

> @rwallace8665 That's correct. A generous DM could certainly turn it into a quiver!

Comment: You may want to add official sources since Crawford's tweets are [no longer official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/41726). In particular, the official rules clarification document, Sage Advice Compendium has addressed a similar question [on page 18](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=18).

Comment: @DavidCoffron Are you referring to the question regarding Mage Armor and shields?

Comment: @Eddymage No, the one about *bracers of defense* and *ring of protection*

Comment: @DavidCoffron Ok, just because you linked the 2017 version of the SAC.

Comment: @Eddymage whoops. I stole that link from another answer...

Comment: This is a significant change from 3.5e and, I believe, 4e, where bonuses had to have a different 'type' in order to stack - I'll have to favorite this question and remember this answer for future use.

Answer (score 10):

The [Attack Rolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#AttackRolls) section in PHB says (emphasis mine):

> To make an attack roll, roll a d20 and add the **appropriate** modifiers.

While in the section of [Damage Rolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#DamageRolls) one reads (emphasis mine):

> Each weapon, spell, and harmful monster ability specifies the damage it deals. You roll the damage die or dice, **add any modifiers**, and apply the damage to your target. Magic weapons, special abilities, and other factors can grant a bonus to damage.

Hence, by a strict reading of the rules you can stack any modifiers you have both for attack and for damage rolls. For the former case, the word *appropriate* leads to include any kind of bonuses the weapon (or ammo) gives, unless the description specify the exceptions.

---

The latest [version](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) of the Sage Advice Compendium addresses a similar question at [pag 21](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=21):

> ***Do the AC bonuses from a ring of protection and bracers of defense stack?*** *Yes. In general, bonuses stack [...]*