# Does the Flame Arrows spell work on magical ammunition?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, ranger

I am making a ranger NPC for a session and I have never played with a high level bow user before. In D&D 5e, does a +3 longbow with+3 Arrows and the ranger spell flame arrows, stack at once for 1d6 Fire damage plus 1d8+6 magical piercing damage without other modifiers?

Basically, can you cast flame arrows on +3 arrows? I am aware that the +3 bow and +3 arrows stack.

Comment: Related (not quite sure if duplicate given the addition of a spell in this question): [Does magical ammunition stack with a magical weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55225/does-magical-ammunition-stack-with-a-magical-weapon)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does magical ammunition stack with a magical weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55225/does-magical-ammunition-stack-with-a-magical-weapon)

Comment: Do you have reason to think you can't cast Flame Arrows on magical ammunition?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## They do stack

*Flame arrows* only necessitates that you draw the ammunition from the affected quiver:

> When a target is hit by a ranged weapon attack using a piece of ammunition drawn from the quiver, the target takes an extra 1d6 fire damage.

The only stipulations for the magic of the Ammunition, +3 and the Weapon, +3 is that you make an attack with them; the bonuses also apply:

> You have a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this piece of magic ammunition. Once it hits a target, the ammunition is no longer magical.
>
> [...]
>
> You have a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon.

No rule specifically restricts this synergy, so the general application of the extra damage and bonuses is valid.

Comment: 'Once it hits a target, the ammunition is no longer magical' suggests that the arrows will no longer be +3 if recovered. So use this at your own risk unless supply isn't an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they stack.

**RAW:**

> You touch a quiver containing ammunition. When a target is hit by a
>   ranged weapon attack using the ammunition, the target takes an extra
>   1d6 fire damage. The spell ends on a piece of ammunition whether it
>   hit or misses, and it can only affect up to 12 pieces in total.
>
> At Higher Levels: The number of pieces of ammunition you can affect
>   with this spell increases by two for each slot level above 3rd.

Conditions to meet:

1. Must be ammunition
2. Must be in the quiver that is enchanted
3. Must hit with a ranged weapon attack using the ammunition

Does the spell include any rules about other bonuses not affecting the item:

- No

Is there any rule precluding the bonuses stacking?

- No

Do you meet these conditions:

1. Is a +3 arrow ammunition?  (Yes)
2. Is the +3 arrow in the quiver when the spell is cast? (assuming yes in your example)
3. Did you hit with the ammunition via a ranged attack?  (Yes, using a bow is a ranged attack, Yes, I'm assuming you did hit for purpose of the answer)

Therefore, since there is no wording stating the Bows bonus cannot be applied it gains the bow's bonus.  Also, since there is no wording stating magical arrow bonuses cannot also be applied it also gains those

So yes, you would gain the +3 from the bow, the +3 from the Arrow and the extra 1d6 fire damage from the spell.

Further, affects like Sharpshooter, Hex or Hunters Mark would also stack, if they apply to your attack, as there is nothing precluding them from doing so in their wording, the items wording or the wording of the spell.

**As to  SeriousBri's comment:**

The spell isn't making the +3 arrow in the example non magical when it hits.  The magic item itself becomes non-magical after it hits a target based on the description of the item.  It has nothing to do with the spell, so there's no added risk by using the spell.